# LED blink with Serial Port

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

This is my Program. It's an Arduino sketch.

```
int bite = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
  bite = Serial.read();
  if(bite != NULL){
    for (int i=0; i < bite; i++){
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
      delay(1000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want the code to check if there is a serial input value and whether it's neither null or a string and blink my LED the number of times as the serial value is received. My code is just blinking the light with and the light is also very dim. It just keeps running. It even happens when I send null to the serial port.

Comment: For every one byte you receive, normally takes 1 millisecond, your program goes off in the woods for 22 seconds to blink the light.  You'll have to type really slow.

Comment: Most serial input possibilities (terminal programs, Arduino SerialMonitor) won't allow you to send null bytes. Theoretically, Serial.read() can read any binary byte stream, but the sender side could be the problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this example code:

```
char incomingByte;
int led=3;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(led,OUTPUT);
   Serial.println("LED control");
   Serial.println("0 = LED off)");
   Serial.println("1 = LED on");
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    incomingByte = Serial.read();
    if(incomingByte == '0'){
       digitalWrite(led,LOW);
    }
    if(incomingByte == '1'){
       digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

So the only thing you probably need to do is to change your `int bite` to `char bite` because of the Serial.read()!

Comment: You forogt the **pinMode(3,OUTPUT)** in your setup(). Or did you try my code and stillt not working?

Comment: well the code still does not make the light run "bite" number of times ad your code is working(the 0 as on and 1 as off thing)

Comment: The problem is by sending a '0' the Serial.read() function returns a '48'. The reason is the ASCII table [which you can see here](http://www.electronicdeveloper.de/Images/ASCII-Tabelle1.PNG). So you need to convert it to an ASCII character e.g. by subtracting 48. But make sure to have the right settings (keyword: carriage return, line feed)

Comment: So if you send a character '2' (e.g. using a Terminal program) you want to have the led blink twice. And what if you send a space , an 'x' , a linefeed, the text "hello world" ???

Comment: @datafiddler i want it to do nothing thats what im saying it should only work when a numeric number is sent

Comment: Maybe this link (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringToIntExample) can help!